# Not able to get current timestamp from postgres using knex

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, datetime, knex.js

I am using Knex and using raw query to get current timestamp of the Postgres database. I am using

```
knex.raw('select now()').then(function(resp)
{
 console.log(resp)
})
```

but I am not able to get the desired result. Please tell me the solution of what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
knex.select(knex.fn.now()).then(res => console.log(res[0].now));
```

Maybe you should also tell what is your desired result.

EDIT: edited query to actually fetch row and column from response, because `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` returns following on postgres:

```
mikaelle=# select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
              now              
-------------------------------
 2018-12-10 14:48:01.472945+02
(1 row)
```

Comment: Array(1) [Object]
campaignDataService.js:52
length:1
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:Object {now: Mon Dec 10 2018 16:11:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard …}
now:Mon Dec 10 2018 16:11:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
__proto__:Object {constructor: , toString: , toDateString: , …}
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}

i am getting result in form of object but not the actual result.